# Can a non-great person claim to be humble?

Tags: meaning

I saw a quote by Golda Meir

> Don't be so humble; you're not that great.

Can a non-great person claim to be humble?

I now wonder if I have misused "humble" in the past. I knew I wasn't great (but not too bad either), but I said I am humble and sincere in a self-evaluation.

Comment: I think this quote can mean about a dozen different things, from "you're trying too hard to be less proud of yourself than you are" (false humility) to "recognize your capacities and achievements for what they are" (in which case the "great" part is ironic) to "self-presentation is not that important because others will always judge you however they see fit" to simply "don't put on airs" to ???

Comment: Argh... this is all just psychology. 'Humble' is usually applied to modest, unimportant, or unexceptional people. So a non-great person is usually humble in front of a great person. But on the scale of greatness, for someone who is great to say that they are humble makes them sound even _more_ great because they are also modest. But knowing that, one might try to say they are humble when they are really not great enough yet to use that false modesty because they might actually be modest for good reason.

Comment: Also, modesty is for people with no talent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,you have not.

I do not know the context of this statement by Golda Meir but I guess being humble in this context means being modest even after being great.So,if a proletarian tries to show how modest then it does not really matter because it is the expected behavior in society.On the other hand,if a celebrity or someone great starts behaving without much pride then we say he is humble.So,if you are behaving modest even after being special(in any sense like you are rich or intelligent) then your usage is not incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

According to Stephen Spector, [*May I Quote You on That?: A Guide to Grammar and Usage*](https://books.google.com/books?id=0BuaCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA347&dq=%22Don%27t+be+so+humble;+you%27re+not+that+great%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTueK5mqvKAhUBxWMKHYHUDuo4ChDoAQgnMAI#v=onepage&q=%22Don%27t%20be%20so%20humble%3B%20you%27re%20not%20that%20great%22&f=false) (2015), Golda Meir's quotation "Don't be so humble. You're not that great." appeared in the *New York Times* of March 18, 1969. Fred Shapiro, [*The Yale Book of Quotations*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ck6bXqt5shkC&pg=PA508&dq=%22Don%27t+be+so+humble;+you%27re+not+that+great%22+1969&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIz_WYm6vKAhVDwGMKHXaFD7kQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=%22Don%27t%20be%20so%20humble%3B%20you%27re%20not%20that%20great%22%201969&f=false) (2006) corroborates Spector's source—or perhaps Spector based his information on the Yale reference work. There is some dispute, however, as to whether Meir was speaking to "an acquaintance" (as [this book from 1998](https://books.google.com/books?id=Pqn0oIq4RdIC&pg=PA132&dq=%22Don%27t+be+so+humble;+you%27re+not+that+great%22+Meir&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjL0NXAnavKAhUCyWMKHeuhA9o4FBDoAQgoMAI#v=onepage&q=%22Don%27t%20be%20so%20humble%3B%20you%27re%20not%20that%20great%22%20Meir&f=false) has it) or to "one of her ministers" (as [this book from 2003](https://books.google.com/books?id=nY4tDDO93E8C&pg=PA189&dq=%22Don%27t+be+so+humble;+you%27re+not+that+great%22+Meir&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNxoeunKvKAhUKzmMKHVqUBPk4ChDoAQgtMAM#v=onepage&q=%22Don%27t%20be%20so%20humble%3B%20you%27re%20not%20that%20great%22%20Meir&f=false) reports) or to "a visiting diplomat" (as [this book from 2005](https://books.google.com/books?id=BQRTAttj4agC&pg=PA196&dq=%22Don%27t+be+so+humble;+you%27re+not+that+great%22+Meir&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNxoeunKvKAhUKzmMKHVqUBPk4ChDoAQhFMAc#v=onepage&q=%22Don%27t%20be%20so%20humble%3B%20you%27re%20not%20that%20great%22%20Meir&f=false) says) or to "General Moshe Dayan" (as [this book from 2012](https://books.google.com/books?id=32gtPDSFNyEC&pg=PA137&dq=%22Don%27t+be+so+humble;+you%27re+not+that+great%22+Meir&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjL0NXAnavKAhUCyWMKHeuhA9o4FBDoAQhNMAk#v=onepage&q=%22Don%27t%20be%20so%20humble%3B%20you%27re%20not%20that%20great%22%20Meir&f=false) insists). Of the four suspects, Dayan seems to be the one cited most frequently.

If Meir did address the comment to Dayan, it is worth noting that he had played a central role in Israel's victory over Egypt, Syria, and Jordan in the Six-Day War of 1967. His generalship was so admired in the late 1960s and early 1970s that President Nixon is said to have offered (jokingly) to trade any three U.S. generals for Dayan; Meir supposedly suggested, as the three U.S. generals she wanted, General Motors, General Electric, and General Dynamics.

In any event, Dayan was widely viewed in 1969 as a brilliant military strategist, which adds a certain sharpness to the second half of Meir's admonition. But viewed at face value, Meir's quotation doesn't mean that only the truly great can be genuinely humble, and that everyone else is just putting on airs in reverse, as Uriah Heep does in *David Copperfield*. Rather, it means that only the greatest of the great can afford not to take credit for their successes. Successful though Dayan has been, Meir implies, it is politically inexpedient for him to downplay his accomplishments.

Answer (score 2):

The context in which Golda Meir communicated this statement was such that being truly humble is something that only the most genuine and selfless people can experience. She's saying that if someone is less than of this level of character, yet responds overly humbly to praise, then they should simply accept the praise graciously and feel perhaps even pride, as this is what most people experience. That is to say, only those of us with the greatest of character can be truly humble.

If you're not that great of character, then you cannot, in essence, be genuinely humble.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is: if any person, no matter, great or non-great, claims to be humble, then this person is not humble. What would you think even of Einstein saying, "I'm a very humble person"? I, for one, couldn't help thinking, "What conceit!" So by the very fact of claiming to be humble you make your claim false. Thus, the original question was put somewhat incorrectly. A correct one, I think, would be this: can people correctly call a non-great person humble? Yes, they can. Because even a non-great, mediocre, lackluster person can imagine and display oneself as great. If he doesn't, then he shows natural, and praiseworthy, humility. But, again, for a great person to think of himself as humble is arrogant, and for non-great, both arrogant and ridiculous.

Comment: I disagree: let's say a famous, widely-admired person is interviewed by a journalist, who asks him "Many people have described you as humble. Do you agree with this assessment?" According to your analysis, the person can't truthfully concur with the assessment that he is humble, or that will be proof of his non-humility. Nor can he truthfully deny that he is humble (assuming he in fact is humble). It seems to me that a truly humble, honest person will find some self-deprecating way to claim that he is humble in a graceful, modest way that doesn't compromise his humility.

Comment: Well, when you are pressed by a pushy enough journalist, you may say many things that are untypical of you. You can say even stranger things under duress (as, for example, many Soviet military leaders confessed in 1937 to being American or/and Japanese spies). What I meant, however, was that Einstein would probably not call himself humble while just talking about himself freely.